# ModuleNotFind Error while importing Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I recently installed the last version of matplotlib. As I try to import into Visual Studio Code I receive this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-2.ipynb Cella 1 in 1
----> 1 import matplotlib

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:109
    105 from packaging.version import parse as parse_version
    107 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    108 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 109 from . import _api, _version, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
    110 from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, sanitize_sequence
    111 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation  # deprecated

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\docstring.py:1
----> 1 from matplotlib._docstring import *  # noqa: F401, F403
      2 from matplotlib import _api
      3 _api.warn_deprecated(
      4     "3.6", obj_type='module', name=f"{__name__}")

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib._docstring'
```

I used pip to install the library.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by upgrading the Python version (from 3.10 to 3.11), pip version and matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Python: Select Interpreter

   [image]
3. Select the interpreter that has `matplotlib` installed.

   [image]